# What do I have to configure to prevent a StaticContentNotFoundException for version.json?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

I am setting up a new DXA2.2 site. When I do an admin refresh, I can see in the logging that various items are downloaded over the service and written to disk, and if I look in the application directory, I can see them. However, it doesn't seem to create version.json, and not very long after I get a StaticContentNotFoundException about this file, as you can see in the following stack trace. I'm assuming that an admin/refresh should create this, but it doesn't. I've looked in the Publish Configuration template to see if it creates version.json, but I couldn't see anything. Where should I be looking? How is this supposed to work? Where does version.json come from?

> 18:40:18.818 [http-nio-8045-exec-7] DEBUG c.t.a.c.cookie.ClaimCookieSerializer - Starting to serialize 1 claims that were received.
> 18:40:18.818 [http-nio-8045-exec-7] DEBUG c.s.w.c.c.i.ClientRequestRetrySupporter - RequestProperties : {Cookie=TAFContext.zip.1=H4sIAAAAAAAAAKtWKklMsypKLSxNLS6xKKgsSBxNLUktKlayqlZy9vcLcfULifdx9XMP8VCyilbSNVSK1VEKDHUNiowPDgny9HMHiuaV5uQARWGqQyIDXBGiAY4hHvGefm7+IO36eTn6iSm5mXn6RalpRanFGUqxtbUAXJUlOYIAAAA, Authorization=Bearer client_id=cduser&Role=cd&FirstName=CD&LastName=User&expiresOn=1596559796496&digest=6u5oBfUQRFvJERKJQgQf_Mi5XklH4VdhBJybs5anE_E=}
> 18:40:18.850 [http-nio-8045-exec-7] DEBUG c.s.d.t.c.GenericStaticContentResolver - Writing binary content to file: D:\code\dxa-xxx2020-site\target\dxa-xxx2020-site-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT\BinaryData\297\nl\system\config\xxx2020.templates.json
> 18:40:18.854 [http-nio-8045-exec-7] DEBUG c.s.w.a.d.DynamicMetaRetrieverImpl - Searching for binaryMeta for url='http://localhost:8045/nl/version.json'.
> 18:40:18.854 [http-nio-8045-exec-7] DEBUG c.s.w.c.c.i.ClientRequestParamsSupporter - ForwardedClaims is configured. Will forward following claims: [taf:session:preview:preview_session, taf:ish:userconditions, taf:ish:userconditions:merged, taf:request:parameters]
> 18:40:18.854 [http-nio-8045-exec-7] DEBUG c.t.a.c.cookie.ClaimCookieSerializer - Starting to serialize 1 claims that were received.
> 18:40:18.854 [http-nio-8045-exec-7] DEBUG c.s.w.c.c.i.ClientRequestRetrySupporter - RequestProperties : {Cookie=TAFContext.zip.1=H4sIAAAAAAAAAKtWKklMsypKLSxNLS6xKKgsSBxNLUktKlayqlZy9vcLcfULifdx9XMP8VCyilbSNVSK1VEKDHUNiowPDgny9HMHiuaV5uQARWGqQyIDXBGiAY4hHvGefm7+IO36eTn6iSm5mXn6RalpRanFGUqxtbUAXJUlOYIAAAA, Authorization=Bearer client_id=cduser&Role=cd&FirstName=CD&LastName=User&expiresOn=1596559796496&digest=6u5oBfUQRFvJERKJQgQf_Mi5XklH4VdhBJybs5anE_E=}
> 18:40:18.854 [http-nio-8045-exec-7] DEBUG c.s.odata.client.DefaultODataClient - Getting entity for query ODataClientQuery[GetDynamicMetaFunctionImport(Url='http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8045%252Fnl%252Fversion.json',ItemType='BinaryMeta')]
> 18:40:18.855 [http-nio-8045-exec-7] DEBUG c.s.o.c.caller.BasicEndpointCaller - Preparing the call endpoint for given url: [https://cd-cont-ace705-dev-eu-west-1-svbnlr8.tridion.sdlproducts.com:8084/client/v4/content.svc/GetDynamicMetaFunctionImport(Url='http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8045%252Fnl%252Fversion.json',ItemType='BinaryMeta')](https://cd-cont-ace705-dev-eu-west-1-svbnlr8.tridion.sdlproducts.com:8084/client/v4/content.svc/GetDynamicMetaFunctionImport(Url=%27http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8045%252Fnl%252Fversion.json%27,ItemType=%27BinaryMeta%27))
> 18:40:18.893 [http-nio-8045-exec-7] DEBUG c.s.o.c.caller.BasicEndpointCaller - Request ended with 200 status code.
> 18:40:18.893 [http-nio-8045-exec-7] DEBUG c.s.o.c.m.AtomEntityUnmarshaller - Unmarshalling entity for query: ODataClientQuery[GetDynamicMetaFunctionImport(Url='http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8045%252Fnl%252Fversion.json',ItemType='BinaryMeta')]
> 18:40:18.893 [http-nio-8045-exec-7] DEBUG c.s.w.a.d.DynamicMetaRetrieverImpl - Could not find Binary metadata by url: http://localhost:8045/nl/version.json
> 18:40:18.894 [http-nio-8045-exec-7] ERROR c.s.w.c.i.l.LocalizationFactoryImpl - No published version.json found for localization [297] /nl
> com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.StaticContentNotFoundException: No binary meta found for pubId: [297] and urlPath: http://localhost:8045/nl/version.json
> at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.content.CilStaticContentResolver.getBinaryMeta(CilStaticContentResolver.java:120)
> at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.content.CilStaticContentResolver.createStaticContentItem(CilStaticContentResolver.java:67)
> at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.content.GenericStaticContentResolver.getStaticContentFileByPath(GenericStaticContentResolver.java:76)
> at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.content.GenericStaticContentResolver.getStaticContent(GenericStaticContentResolver.java:42)
> at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultContentProvider.getStaticContent(DefaultContentProvider.java:226)
> at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.loadVersionFromBroker(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:170)

Update: Now that Velu has pointed me in the right direction, the question is not so much how can I make sure version.json is there, but how do I make sure I don't need it.

Comment: @I'm sure it's  read values from HTML Design Configuration Component from CMS from this Publish Html Design Page. refer to this TBB code reference https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/bc6e8fd99bc70771c49485d13e3ea8eaeed458e6/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates/Templates/PublishHtmlDesign.cs

Comment: maybe try access any page to see that file downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Version.json** value managed in the CMS in the **"HTML Design Configuration"** component in this path **100 Master\Building Blocks\Settings\Core\Site Manager**

And this component is used in **Publish HTML Design** page and got published to DXD using this TBB **[Publish HTML Design](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/bc6e8fd99bc70771c49485d13e3ea8eaeed458e6/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates/Templates/PublishHtmlDesign.cs#L55)**.

[image]

**Note:**

**For Java:**
please note that when not publishing the HTML design you can provide the version number in **dxa.properties** by adding a **dxa.assets.version** property

**Updated:**
**For .NET:**

- It may be that the version JSON file is 'unmanaged', ie just placed on the filesystem manually
- In which case we try to load it directly - the HTML Design is thus not published from CMS

> [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory]/system/assets\version.json

- HTML design is not published nor does the file exist on disk. Setting version to v0.0

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Velu. You sent me in the right direction. My app does not use the HTML design, so actually I was probably asking the wrong question. If you update your answer to note that when not publishing the HTML design you can provide the version number in dxa.properties by adding a dxa.assets.version property, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Updated @DominicCronin :-)

Comment: "please note that when not publishing the HTML design you can provide the version number in dxa.properties by adding a dxa.assets.version property" How do you set the version in .NET DXA?

Comment: Probably in the web.config

Comment: Updated @AtilaSos and Dominic for .NET DXA, Here is the code reference https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/a51b99639821db084ac98a5046ec0f58fc299fee/Sdl.Web.Common/Configuration/Localization.cs#L432